Calling `free` syscall for the first element array of void* in C
Here's a snippet of C code:
int main()
{
    void **values = calloc(10, sizeof(void *));

    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a = 100;
    int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *b = 200;

    values[0] = a;
    values[1] = b;

    values[0] = NULL;
    free(values);

    values[1] = NULL;
    free(values);

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}

The question is: why doesn't it cause a segmentation error? Since it attempts to reach an forbidden region. Of course Valgrind show errors in details but running the program doesn't make any errors.
I've also ran the code with void **values = calloc(1, sizeof(void *)); and the same result.
Also if you try to change the values[1] = NULL to values [2] (with 10 blocks of void*), it complains about segmentation fault.

There is no guarantee that a mistake will cause a segfault. There is no "code police" in C: only if you damage something or access what you are not allowed.

Dereferencing an invalid pointer (for example one that you have passed to free) leads to undefined behavior. Just don't do that.

@Someprogrammerdude I know this is a code with flaws, but can you explain why changing values[1] = NULL to values[2] = NULL causes error? despite the values[1] = NULL is wrong.

@WeatherVane What does make a difference between values[1] = NULL and values[2] = NULL why both are wrong. Note that commenting the values[1] = b; doesn't change the result of the program.

Undefined behavior is undefined. It might seem to work, it might crash the program, it might even summon nasal demons. Okay, perhaps not the last, but there's really nothing that can be said in a general manner.

values[1] = b; was fine. The values[1] = NULL; would have been OK except you already did free(values);.

@Someprogrammerdude You mean it may shows the error for values[1] = NULL in like 1000 times runs, right? Does it depend on the OS or the compiler? if so, which parameters are included?

For a broader discussion please see Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior.

@WeatherVane Is the conclusion correct that after running the two versions of the code each 1000 time, and finding the same result for each, it's an intended behavior in implementation?

No. The behaviour may repeatly work on one machine, but fail on another. Or it may fail on the same machine if a change is made to another part of the code, as has been explained.

What is undefined behavior and how does it work?

When you attempt to access memory that has already been freed, or attempt to free memory more than once, that triggers undefined behavior in your code.
With undefined behavior, your program may crash, it may output strange results, or (as in your case) it could appear to work properly. Also, making a seemingly unrelated change such as adding an unused local variable or adding a printf for debugging can change how undefined behavior manifests itself.
Just because a program could crash doesn't mean it will.

What does make a difference between values[1] = NULL and values[2] = NULL while both are wrong? I ran it a couple of times and it always raises an error for changing this line of the code.

@shayanrokrok That's part of undefined behavior.  Ultimately, it has to do with implementation details of the OS, compiler, and/or standard libraries.

Is the conclusion correct that after running the two versions of the code each 1000 time, and finding the same result for each, it's an intended behavior in implementation?

@shayanrokrok Not likely. I dare to say that no standard library implementation defines what will happen if you access memory that's already been freed, even if you've observed the same behavior 10000000 times. You could of course use a third party allocator library that never returns memory to its pool (where free is a no-op) and such a library could give the guarantee that allocated memory will stay valid and accessible for the whole program run. I doubt such a library exists and even if it does, you are most likely not using one.

The C standard does not guarantee anything about using memory that is released from allocation.
By and large, the memory management routines are merely bureaucratic record-keeping routines. They track which memory has been reserved for your C code to use. About the only other guaranteed behavior from them is that, once memory is reserved for your C code to use, there will be actual memory available at that location in your virtual address space. (And that is not even guaranteed by some operating systems.)
When you call malloc or calloc, the memory management software plans some space in memory, makes a record that that space is reserved, and, if not already done for that memory, asks the operating system to make virtual memory available for it.
When you call free, the memory management software updates the record to say the space is no longer reserved.
That is all it is required to do. Keep records. It is not required to mark the memory as no longer accessible. It is not required to watch the rest of your program to make sure it no longer accesses that memory. It is not required to erase the memory. It is not required not to erase that memory.
Memory management software might or might not do these things. Some software has debugging features that do some of these things. But, by and large, the default is to do little more than record-keeping.
